# Updating SQL Server query loop until X number reached

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I am in need of updating a few rows in a database at the same time. Now the issue is that I will only know the FIRST row's unique ID but I will have X number of other rows after that that will need to be updated with some data as well. I will know how many loops I will need in order to update them - just need to know how to go about doing it.

My query looks like this:

```
UPDATE bLine 
SET @val1 
WHERE theGuid = @val2;
```

Now the data for @val1 looks like this:

```
ID | qty_SerialNum | qty_Location | qty_Property | theGUID 
---+---------------+--------------+--------------+---------------------------
5  | 6845fg56      | Home         | NA           | a45vz-u300-2bd-4710j-vf09
6  | fk469fkh      | Dock#4       | NA           |
7  | geww2         | Dock#1       | Local        |
...
```

Which when in a string to send over for the **@val1**:

```
@val1 = qty_SerialNum = '6845fg56,fk469fkh,geww2',
        qty_Location = 'Home,Dock#4,Dock#1',
        qty_Property = 'NA,NA,Local' 
@val2 = theGUID = 'a45vz-u300-2bd-4710j-vf09'
```

So that's all fine since I know the **GUID** of the **first row** that needs updating but **every row after** that I **wont know**.

So the 1st update would look like out of 3:

```
UPDATE
   bLine
SET
   (qty_SerialNum = '6845fg56',qty_Location = 'Home',qty_Property = 'NA' )
WHERE 
   theGuid = 'a45vz-u300-2bd-4710j-vf09';
```

And this would be the 2nd update out of 3:

```
UPDATE
   bLine
SET
   (qty_SerialNum = 'fk469fkh',qty_Location = 'Dock#4',qty_Property = 'NA' )
WHERE 
   ???? = ????;
```

And finally this would be the 3rd update out of 3:

```
UPDATE
   bLine
SET
   (qty_SerialNum = 'geww2',qty_Location = 'Dock#1',qty_Property = 'Local' )
WHERE 
   ???? = ????;
```

So the question here is - how can I **loop through the next X rows** and **update** that information with the 2,3,... values in @val1 (skipping the first since its already saved via the theGUID)?

Comment: But what is the order of your records? You say X rows after the found one but you don't explain what is the order in which those _next_ rows should be

Comment: @Steve the order would be the same. It will correspond to however many rows are left to update. they will always be in that same order for each row after the main one (the one with the GUID)

Comment: Updated my OP with a little more information

Comment: maybe start with your data and the desired result...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can treat this as a gaps and islands type problem where you need to update and island row(row containing guid as well all gap rows till next island).

I am taking some assumption here and below is a <kbd>**[working demo](http://rextester.com/OKLR40843)**</kbd>

```
create table bline (ID int, qty_SerialNum varchar(100),qty_Location varchar(100),qty_Property varchar(100), theGUID  varchar(100))
insert into bline values 
(5,'random','garbage','existing','a45vz-u300-2bd-4710j-vf09')
,(6,'data','random','garbage', NULL)
,(7,'existing','data','.', NULL);

create table #V (qty_SerialNum varchar(100),qty_Location varchar(100),qty_Property varchar(100))
insert into #V values
('6845fg56','Home','NA'),
('fk469fkh','Dock#4','NA'),
('geww2','Dock#1','Local')


;with map as
  (
       select id, 
          rn=row_number() over ( order by id asc) 
       from bline 
          where theGUID is NOT NULL
   ),
mappedBline as
   (
       select 
           b1.*,
           rn
       from
           bline b1 join
       (
           select b.id,
               rn=max(rn)
           from bline b 
               join map m
                   on b.id >=m.id
           group by b.id
         )b2 
       on b2.id=b1.id
     ),
updateSet as
    (
        select 
            M.*, 
            updaterow=row_number() over( order by M.id)
        from mappedBline M join
          mappedBline M2 
              on M.rn=M2.rn 
                and M2.theGUID = 'a45vz-u300-2bd-4710j-vf09' --@val2
     )

 update U
     set
         qty_SerialNum=V.qty_SerialNum,
         qty_Location= V.qty_Location,
         qty_Property =V.qty_Property
 from
 updateSet U join
 ( select 
      *, updaterow =row_number() over (order by (select NULL))
  from #V
  )V
  on U.updaterow=V.updaterow

select * from bline
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a very arcane problem.  In general, SQL updates are not for "adjancent" rows in this fashion.  However, you can make it work by storing the values in a (virtual) table and joining the two sides together:

```
with v as (
      select v.*
      from (values (1, '6845fg56', 'Home', 'NA'),
                   (2, 'fk469fkh', 'Dock#4', 'NA'),
                   (3, 'geww2', 'Dock#1', 'Local')
           ) v(seqnum, qty_SerialNum, qty_Location, qty_Property)
     )
update b
   set qty_SerialNum = v.qty_SerialNum,
       qty_Location = v.qty_Location,
       qty_Property = v.qty_Property
    from (select top(3) b.*,
                 row_number() over (order by id) as seqnum
          from bline b
          where id >= (select id from bline where theGUID = 'a45vz-u300-2bd-4710j-vf09'
          order by id
         ) b join
         v
         on b.seqnum = v.seqnum;
```